# iOS 7 transition: TableView content hidden under navigation bar after a memory warning

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uinavigationbar

I'm transitioning an existing app to iOS 7. It's a **tab bar application**, and each tab has a table view controller embedded in a navigation controller. I'm using storyboard and have enabled Adjust Scroll View Insets and am using the translucent navigation bar.
Everything looks fine when I run the app. The table view content sits nicely under the navigation bar.

When I simulate a memory warning, the not visible table views unload. When they load again, the top of the table view is now underneath the navigation bar. Also a warning appears on the console, just before the view loads:

> *The top layout guide length constraint unexpectedly lost its container. Did the application remove all constraints from the view controller's view (which would be an app error)?*

I'm not using auto layout, but turning it on did not make any difference. 
Calling `[self setEdgesForExtendedLayout: UIRectEdgeNone]` in `viewDidLoad` solves the problem, but then I don't get the nice effect of the background showing through the navigation bar.

Why is the behaviour different when reloading after a memory warning? What causes the top layout constraint warning? Any clues to how I could fix this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Solution yet? @primulaveris